# Connect to Windows VM on Google Cloud using Python Package

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform

Can anyone suggest some package or script which can help me connect windows server vm on gcp
from a program.

I am able to connect through RDP but don't want to do that way .

Also I am not able to generate public key and private key on gcp . If someone can describe how to ? That will help too

My Local OS : **Windows 10** , Language : **Python 3.7**

Cloud Hosted VM : **Windows Data Center Server 2019**

Comment: When you says `connect` what exactly do you mean? 1) Windows supports RDP for remote desktop. 2) If you want to use SSH like Linux systems, install `OpenSSH`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_overview

Comment: @JohnHanley how to use rdp in python code to connect remote windows machine and for e.g. list directories from cmd prompt

Comment: Look at Python libraries like: https://pypi.org/project/rdpy/. However, I recommend installing OpenSSH on Windows and using SSH which is well supported in Python.

Comment: @JohnHanley thanks but OpenSSH support only non windows os . I need something else i.e for windows. So i can send command like ' dir ' from python code same as we do on cmd prompt

Comment: Windows Server comes with Microsoft's version of OpenSSH. Install and configure it. Click on the link I provided in my first comment. I use it all the time.

Comment: Thanks @JohnHanley
Hope I was not a troublesome for you. I am new to cloud and server remote access